# package com.adventnet.snmp.snmp2 not found exception

Tags: java, weblogic

I am building a project and am getting the following error.

```
error package com.adventnet.snmp.snmp2 not found exception
```

I am migrating projects from `weblogic10` to `weblogic12c` server. In my classpath, I have added the jars in lib and modules of `weblogic12c`.

Comment: Which IDE do you use?

Comment: STS (Springsource tool suite)

Comment: But for compiling i am using ant script.